# How to deploy a client/server website with Express, Vue.js, and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, axios, google-cloud-functions

I developed a website using Vue.js (for the front-end) and made a server to connect this website to an API (here it's Twitter). The server is made with Express.js. In localhost, everything is working. I have my server on localhost:8085 which is running, my website on localhost:8080. I can access data thanks to the Api through, for example, GET http://localhost:8085/TheNameOfTheApiFunction.

Because I want to deploy my website easily, I tried with Heroku and Firebase. I make "npm run build" with the front-end, put the result in the "public" directory of my server, the firebase.json is fine (I think).

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function":"app",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

At this point, when I launch the website, the front end is working but has no access to any of the API function. Seems logical because there is no localhost/8085 to ask functions to.
`GET http://localhost:8085/NameOfTheApiFunction net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Because of this, I decided to explore the reasons and found that I should use what is propose in this tutorial :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework.
So I copy-and-pasted what was in my app.js file to the index.js file create by firebase functions (in the functions directory). But it's not working.

What should I do to have a good deployment ? Should I change what is in the client in API.js for it to be adaptative ?

```
export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: `http://localhost:8085/`
    })
}
```

**EDIT**
To be clear.

1. In the folder "myapp", I have the folder "client", there's my Vue.js front-end website in it and I launch it locally with `npm run serve`.
2. In the same folder "myapp", I have the folder "server", which was necessary to connect to the Twitter Api, because it's not possible from the front-end. I launch it by doing "npm run start".
3. My front-end acces to the "server" with Axios. The server anwser with get or post and is capable of asking information to the twitter API.
4. Everything work just fine on localhost. I want to deploy the website and I followed this video :
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJwHevf2wYE
   The guy suggest to create a folder named "public" in the server part, in which you put all the files that come from the build (npm run build) of the "client". You add `app.use(express.static("public"))` in the server and when I launch, for example, localhost:8085 (i.e. the server) I can access the whole website in one command (and not two).
5. Because this was working, I thougth I could launch the website by deploying the "server" folder. But it's not working, and I think this is because the "client" side is coded to ask for "localhost:8085/ApiFunctions". But I don't understand how I should deploy the server. That's why I tried to use firebase hosting, but I have the exact same problem : I don't understand exactly how this is running to know if the problem comes from my deployment method or the code(axios having baseURL: localhost:8085).

Comment: If you're serving the Vue app from the Express app, it can make _relative_ requests. Then you don't need configuration at all, just a dev proxy when you're running it locally. Have a look at how I set it up [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture), for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've read the page. This is the architecture I tried to use for Heroku, but like I said, I don't understand what I should put in the BaseURL of Axios to have a relative path ! Could you explain ?

Comment: Nothing, if you're using relative paths you don't need a base URL.

Comment: How should I use relative path ? And, maybe I don't understand what you mean by relative path

Comment: `axios.method('/NameOfTheApiFunction')`. Basically what you do _with_ a base URL configured, except without a base URL. Then they're made _relative_ to whatever origin the page is loaded on, which because the Express server is providing both the APIs _and_ the client app assets is the same thing you'd put for the base URL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that:

1. Your Vue.js app is served through the Firebase Hosting service.
2. You pass your Express app to an HTTP Cloud Function, as explained in the doc you refer to and also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) in the Cloud Functions doc.

If this understanding is correct, you can access your Express JS app (i.e. the Cloud Function) at the following URLs, as explained at [the bottom of the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#deploy-function) (bullet point #2):

- Your Firebase subdomains: `<Firebase_project_ID>.web.app/<NameOfTheApiFunction>` and `<Firebase_project_ID>.firebaseapp.com/<NameOfTheApiFunction>`
- Or, any connected custom domains:
  `<custom_domain>/<NameOfTheApiFunction>`.

---

**UPDATE FOLLOWING YOUR COMMENT:**

It seems you want to access the CF while using the emulator. You should either use the emulator default port for Cloud Functions i.e. 5001, or configure it with another port, as desired. See the Emulators [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#port_configuration).

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer !

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how to deploy my express server accurately.

Comment: I would suggest to first try a deployment on Firebase, to avoid any additional complexity with the Emulator. When you are sure your Vue.js app + your cloud function + the connectivity from the front-end to the CF work correctly, you can then solve the potential emulators problems. To deploy the CF, follow the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Comment: So :
1. I change in my "client" folder, the Axios connection from ```
export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: `http://localhost:8085/`
    })
}``` to "<Firebase_project_ID>.firebaseapp.com/<NameOfTheApiFunction>"
2. I deploy the front-end from "client" with firebase like I did before.
3. I deploy the server with Cloud Function and it will be available at the adress. 

?

Comment: Also it is important to understand the difference between the Vue.js and the Firebase projects.

Comment: Answer to your last comment (1, 2 & 3): normally yes!

Comment: another problem came with the Cloud Function

Comment: Hello @TomPelletreauDuris, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hello @RenaudTarnec ! Thank you very much, after a week of errors and debug it's now working ! I had some issues with the Cloud function and the deployment (mainly caused by ESLINT) and now every thing is ok. Thank you very much, you were a great help !